# Regular, repeating, interaction between an oracle and a smart contract

Tags: oracle, blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

This is just an example. I'm building this dapp where I have a start date and an end date and every day I want to get a random number from an oracle. If at some point the sum of the numbers I get every day exceeds a threshold then an OK message returns to my backend. Let's assume we have a range of 7 days.

Day 1:

- My backend sends a request to the "smart contract Number" and calls the requestOk () method.
- The smart contract Number calls the gethNumber () method of the oracle smart contract and passes it the callback on which to return the response.
- The oracle smart contract issues an updateN () event
- The oracle service retrieves the data and returns it to the oracle smart contract by calling the UpdateNumber () method
- The oracle smart contract uses the callback and returns the data to the smart contract Number
- The smart contract Number checks if the number received that day is greater than a threshold. If it is greater, an ok message returns to the backande, otherwise the same procedure is performed for day 2, I take the new number and add it to the number of day 1. Finally I compare the sum (day number 1 + day number 2) with the threshold and so on.

Now my question is: can the operations I have to perform again for day 2 automatically start from the smart contract Number? I mean, is it possible to create a mechanism allows the smart contract Number to ask the oracle for a random number every day for a week? Or must it be my backend asking to do the same operations for day 2 and every day of the week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or must it be my backend asking to do the same operations for day 2 and every day of the week?

Yes.