# interaction with smart contract oracle

Tags: oracle, blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

Is it possible for a smart contract to make calls to the Oracle in loop (as long as a condition is met) in a dapp? For example: a loop which makes calls to the oracle which returns the result on a callback.
Or does the backand have to make one call at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Because all transactions are executed synchronously, it is not possible for oracle state to change during the loop.

You cannot sleep() in a smart contract, so your question does not make any sense in the first place.

Comment: Actually I asked a more specific question here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65944313/interaction-between-smart-contract-and-oracle-contract)